# Python Standardize specific data Sckit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, scaling, standardized

I want to standardize my dataset to a specific  range (5.5,7.5). How can I do this?
ı try feature_range parameters,but I could not succeed

Comment: Have you tried [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)?

Comment: #1.adım
X = df[['BORC','ALACAK']]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train1, X_test1 = train_test_split(X, test_size=0.3)

Comment: #from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
#scaler1 = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(5.5,6.5))
#scaler2 = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(5,7.7))
#scaler1.fit(X_train1[0].reshape(-1,1))
#max(scaler1.fit_transform(X_train1)[0]),
max(scaler1.fit_transform(X_train1)[0])    I GET  5.5 values, why ?